# Performance issue with $where clause in mongodb v3.0.7

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have collection with 104444219 records, when I perform full scan of collection it takes around 38038 milliseconds with the query

```
db.ORDER_MASTER.find()
```

But while performing query with `$where` clause

```
db.ORDER_DETALS.find({ "$where" : "this.GLB_ROOT_ORDER_ID == this.SYS_ORDER_ID"})
```

Also we have indexes on `GLB_ROOT_ORDER_ID` and `SYS_ORDER_ID`, on the same collection it takes 2064391 milliseconds while checking explain plan for both queries doing full scan, but why difference in execution time?

Is there any alternative for `$where` clause?

For

```
db.ORDER_MASTER.find({ "$where" : "obj.GLB_ROOT_ORDER_ID == obj.SYS_ORDER_ID"})
```

**explain results**

```
{
        "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "uat_test.ORDER_MASTER",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                        "$where" : "obj.GLB_ROOT_ORDER_ID == obj.SYS_ORDER_ID"
                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                        "filter" : {
                                "$where" : "obj.GLB_ROOT_ORDER_ID == obj.SYS_ORDER_ID"
                        },
                        "direction" : "forward"
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
        },
        "executionStats" : {
                "executionSuccess" : true,
                "nReturned" : 93366348,
                "executionTimeMillis" : 2064391,
                "totalKeysExamined" : 0,
                "totalDocsExamined" : 104444219,
                "executionStages" : {
                        "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                        "filter" : {
                                "$where" : "obj.GLB_ROOT_ORDER_ID == obj.SYS_ORDER_ID"
                        },
                        "nReturned" : 93366348,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 2007680,
                        "works" : 104444221,
                        "advanced" : 93366348,
                        "needTime" : 11077872,
                        "needFetch" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 816961,
                        "restoreState" : 816961,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "docsExamined" : 104444219
                }
        },

        "ok" : 1
}
```

For

```
db.ORDER_MASTER.find()
```

**explain results**

```
{
        "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "uat_test.ORDER_MASTER",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                        "$and" : [ ]
                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                        "filter" : {
                                "$and" : [ ]
                        },
                        "direction" : "forward"
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
        },
        "executionStats" : {
                "executionSuccess" : true,
                "nReturned" : 104444219,
                "executionTimeMillis" : 38038,
                "totalKeysExamined" : 0,
                "totalDocsExamined" : 104444219,
                "executionStages" : {
                        "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                        "filter" : {
                                "$and" : [ ]
                        },
                        "nReturned" : 104444219,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 26520,
                        "works" : 104444221,
                        "advanced" : 104444219,
                        "needTime" : 1,
                        "needFetch" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 815970,
                        "restoreState" : 815970,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "docsExamined" : 104444219
                }
        },

        "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: There is lttle point in posting the `.explain()` output since that is mostly about "index usage" and `$where` cannot use an "index". The nature of your expression "requires" a "collection scan", and that means it needs to process every document in the collection in order to see if they match the condition. So "slow results" can only be expected. Don't rely on queries requiring the equality of two elements. Restructure. Store a field indicating whether that condition is `true/false` directly in the document. That way you get a fast query that "can" use an "index".

Comment: Of course though "restructure" is in order for best results, you should see an improvement with `.aggregate()` instead. `db.ORDER_MASTER.aggregate({ "$redact": { "$cond": { "if": { "$eq": [ "$GLB_ROOT_ORDER_ID", "$SYS_ORDER_ID" ] }, "then": "$$KEEP", "else": "$$PRUNE" } } })`. "Part" of the problem is the JavaScript evaluation takes longer than the native operators to evaluate. So this removes the "JavaScript" from the equation.